# how to change the password in ssh server credential in jenkins programatically

Tags: jenkins, ssh, passwords

I have hundreds of Jenkins jobs that use the build step "`Send files or execute commands over SSH`". this step requires a **credential to the SSH server**.

The password expires every 90 days as company police. To update the password for all the jobs is painful and time consuming.

**Is it possible at all to change the password programmatically**, e.g. using `CURL, python-jenkins` ...?

The password is encrypted/hashed, simply replacing the text of the tag `<secretPassphrase>` in the **config.xml** file with one from another job that manually updated does not seem working

Answer (score 0):

You can Create Groovy Script and run it with "Script Console" to Get a Password from credentials.xml and edit that password according to New changes.

You can Fetch Your Credentials within Jenkins using Script Console. here is the Script for this: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2191/how-to-decrypt-jenkins-passwords-from-credentials-xml

You can Fetch your Credentials and then edit these same credentials using Groovy.

another Solution is to use configuration as a code plugin and create new Credentials with yaml syntax and update the new credentials to the job with the Groovy File.

Comment: I'm not asking how to get the encrypted password or the actual password, instead, i need help to update the jobs with the new password, PROGRAMATICALLY. what i did: `manually update the password for job_1, get the config1.xml of job1, get the encrypted  pass word from config1.xml; get config2.xml of job2, update config2.xml with the encrypted password in config1.xml, run curl post, and use python jenkins reconfig_job(job2, config2.xml)`. it does not work either curl or python jenkins reconfiure_jobs.